# Need a vertical tabview in xhtml page

Tags: jsf, xhtml, primefaces

I need to have a vertical tabview in my xhtml page. I see that it's possible to do that using Primwe Faces p:tabview Orientation="left", but i'm using Primefaces 2.2.1, and Orientation attribute does not seem to work in that. I cannot use jQuery either. Is there some way I can achieve the effects of a vertical tab view with Orientation left (like in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewOrientation.jsf) with primefaces 2.2.1?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Raaz.

Answer (score 0):

In Primefaces 2.2.1 is impossible to have a Vertical tab view, unless you modify the component by yourself (I wouldn't suggest that)
You can use, however a component from other JSF implemetation such as openfaces ( http://openfaces.org/demo/tabset/TabSet_placementAndStyling.jsf ) but you'll need again to adjust CSS styles to look like the primefaces theme you're using.